# EC2 Ubuntu instance with 30GB free space on attached volume says no space left on device

Tags: docker, disk-space, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance on AWS with 30GB volume attached. When running docker to build an image though, I am encountering this issue of no space left on device.

Actually, running `df -h` I can see `/dev/root` is almost full, but I still have this volume attached with 30 GB free space that I can't seem to be able to utilize.

`df -h` shows:

```
Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        7.6G  6.8G  876M  89% /
tmpfs            463M     0  463M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            185M  932K  185M   1% /run
tmpfs            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/nvme1n1      30G  657M   28G   3% /mnt/ebs_volume
/dev/nvme0n1p15  105M  6.1M   99M   6% /boot/efi
tmpfs             93M  4.0K   93M   1% /run/user/1000
```

`lsblk` shows:

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0          7:0    0  24.9M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/7628
loop1          7:1    0 105.4M  1 loop /snap/core/16574
loop2          7:2    0  45.2M  1 loop /snap/certbot/3643
loop3          7:3    0  25.2M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/7911
loop4          7:4    0  63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/2015
loop5          7:5    0  74.2M  1 loop /snap/core22/1122
loop6          7:6    0  55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2812
loop7          7:7    0  63.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2182
loop8          7:8    0 130.1M  1 loop /snap/docker/2915
loop9          7:9    0 111.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24322
loop10         7:10   0    87M  1 loop /snap/lxd/27037
loop11         7:11   0  40.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20290
loop12         7:12   0  40.4M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20671
nvme1n1      259:0    0    30G  0 disk /mnt/ebs_volume
nvme0n1      259:1    0     8G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1  259:2    0   7.9G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p14 259:3    0     4M  0 part
└─nvme0n1p15 259:4    0   106M  0 part /boot/efi
```

Comment: We probably need more information - what does df -h actually show?   What does the output of lsblk show?

Comment: I edited the question with the informations, thank you!

Comment: what is the output of `dd if=/dev/zero of=zero.tmp iflag=fullblock status=progress; rm -f zero.tmp;`  ?

Answer (score 2):

The `30GB` EBS volume you are referring to should be `/dev/nvme1n1` that is mounted on `/mnt/ebs_volume`. To use it, please place all your user generated content on that volume.

Alternately, you can create `bind` mounts (using option `bind`) to mount this directory at other paths too, as below (making a `deployments` subdirectory in `ebs_volume`):

```
mount --bind /mnt/ebs_volume/deployments /home/deployments
```

The above can be done using the `fstab` as follows:

```
# Mount /mnt/ebs_volume/deployments on /home/deployments
/mnt/ebs_volume/deployments /home/deployments none bind
```

Similarly, other subdirectories in `/mnt/ebs_volume` can be created and mounted at all points you require more space like `/var/lib/docker`.